# Assigning datasource to binding source throws exception

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this below logic in my code.

```
Initialize(){
    DataGridView view = new DataGridView();
    view.BindingSource = bs;
    bs.dataSource = dataTable;

    //Fill Data Table using Adapter.
    da.fill(dataTable);
}

CallMeEveryFewMinutes(DataTable dataTable){
    List<String> changed = findChangedOjbects();
    // Fill datatable2 with changed objects.
    da2.fill(datatable2, changed)     

    Refresh(dataTable, datatable2);
    // dataTable is now refreshed. Bind it again so changes are reflected.

    // ********** PROBLEM AREA ***************
    // once in a while it throws the below exception.
    bs.dataSource = dataTable;
}
```

Not only that, it also throws the same exception for datagridview.sort(...) - once in a while ..

Any pointers will be really helpful.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the    target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: rowIndex
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean cutOverflow)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCellAdjustedDisplayRectangle(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean cutOverflow)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.InvalidateCellPrivate(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellCommonChange(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.ProcessListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.currencyManager_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.CancelCurrentEdit()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.CancelRowEdit(Boolean restoreRow, Boolean addNewFinished)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.OnRowValidating(DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowValidating(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_CurrentCell(DataGridViewCell value)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnClearingRows()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.ClearInternal(Boolean recreateNewRow)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.RefreshColumnsAndRows()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.DataSourceMetaDataChanged()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.ProcessListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.currencyManager_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetBindings(Boolean metadataChanged)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.SetList(IList list, Boolean metaDataChanged, Boolean applySortAndFilter)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetList()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_DataSource(Object value)
>      at Caddie.ViewHelper.MainForm.FormHelper.refreshWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in C:\Project\Project_1.9\WindowsFormsApplication\ViewHelper\MainForm\FormHelper.cs:line 373
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object arg)

Answer (score 1):

I found a very good hint from

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/279d3c64-c1c2-4927-b0cc-79866c09e035/

"I figured it out but posted on another thread.  Basically the currency manager which has made its own index of the data, is getting out of wack.  In my collection object I've allowed for myself to pass in the datagridview object so that if anything gets deleted I can call the bindingmanager.resetcurrentbindings.  If you reset the bindings after deletes then that will avoid this error."

So, I changed my code a little and the problem (looks like) is now resolved.

```
Initialize(){
    DataGridView view = new DataGridView();
    view.BindingSource = bs;
    bs.dataSource = dataTable;

    //Fill Data Table using Adapter.
    da.fill(dataTable);
}

CallMeEveryFewMinutes(DataTable dataTable){
    List<String> changed = findChangedOjbects();
    // Fill datatable2 with changed objects.
    da2.fill(datatable2, changed)     

    Refresh(dataTable, datatable2);
    // dataTable is now refreshed. Bind it again so changes are reflected.

    // ********** PROBLEM AREA -- SOLVED ***************
    // once in a while it throws the below exception.
    //bs.dataSource = dataTable; don't rebind the same datatable, but rather reset the bindings.
    bs.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption here is that due to you modifying the data, and rebinding it to the control, some event that listens to the grid itself is being called. Whether it be a SelectionChanged, or maybe RowRemoved, you are basically attempting to run these calls against a Gridview with no data in it.

Check your event listeners and see if you have any calls to methods that would attempt to access data within your grid. You could even put some break points within your program to see in what order these methods are being called. When the rebind happens, watch the order in which the code is called.

To remedy this, on the event listeners check whether or not dgv.Rows.Count is equal to 0 or not.

Comment: Thanks fore the response, I found out that instead of rebinding the same data table to binding source, we should instead "reset bindings" this is enable control (data grid view) to refresh their contents before any thing else executes (like listeners)